# xpath-router doesn't route message with xpath-expression

Tags: java, spring, xpath, spring-integration

I use Spring Integration XML router with `xpath-expression`

```
<int:chain input-channel="routerInputChannel">
    <int-xml:xpath-router default-output-channel="routerOutputChannel">
        <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="//actor[1]/text()"/>
        <int-xml:mapping value="Christian Bale" channel="routerBaleChannel"/>
    </int-xml:xpath-router>
</int:chain>
```

and expect that this XML string as a SI message payload

```
<root xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
    <actors>
        <actor id="1">Christian Bale</actor>
        <actor id="2">Liam Neeson</actor>
        <actor id="3">Michael Caine</actor>
    </actors>
    <foo:singers>
        <foo:singer id="4">Tom Waits</foo:singer>
        <foo:singer id="5">B.B. King</foo:singer>
        <foo:singer id="6">Ray Charles</foo:singer>
    </foo:singers>
</root>
```

will be send to `routerBaleChannel` but it doesn't work for some reason.

I tried the message and XPath expression at [XPath Tester / Evaluator](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) and as expected I've got `Christian Bale` string.

I debugged `org.springframework.integration.xml.router.XPathRouter` method `getChannelKeys` and see some problem inside `Jaxp13XPathExpressionFactory` method `evaluate`: for unknown reason after execution

`NodeList nodes = (NodeList) evaluate(node, XPathConstants.NODESET);`

`nodes.getLength()` returns empty list.

So what is wrong with my XPath router or XPath expression configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
<int:chain input-channel="inputChannel">
    <int-xml:xpath-router>
        <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="//actor[1]/text()"/>
        <int-xml:mapping value="Christian Bale" channel="routerBaleChannel"/>
    </int-xml:xpath-router>
</int:chain>

<int:channel id="routerBaleChannel">
    <int:queue/>
</int:channel>
```

...

```
@Test
public void testSO45173221() {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ac =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("XPathRouterTests-context.xml", this.getClass());
    MessageChannel inputChannel = ac.getBean("inputChannel", MessageChannel.class);
    PollableChannel channelBale = ac.getBean("routerBaleChannel", PollableChannel.class);
    GenericMessage<String> message =
            new GenericMessage<>("<root xmlns:foo=\"http://www.foo.org/\" xmlns:bar=\"http://www.bar.org\">\n" +
            "    <actors>\n" +
            "        <actor id=\"1\">Christian Bale</actor>\n" +
            "        <actor id=\"2\">Liam Neeson</actor>\n" +
            "        <actor id=\"3\">Michael Caine</actor>\n" +
            "    </actors>\n" +
            "    <foo:singers>\n" +
            "        <foo:singer id=\"4\">Tom Waits</foo:singer>\n" +
            "        <foo:singer id=\"5\">B.B. King</foo:singer>\n" +
            "        <foo:singer id=\"6\">Ray Charles</foo:singer>\n" +
            "    </foo:singers>\n" +
            "</root>");
    inputChannel.send(message);
    Message<?> result = channelBale.receive(0);
    assertNotNull(result);
    assertEquals(message.getPayload(), result.getPayload());
    ac.close();
}
```

Not sure what's going on in your case...

Although I'm on Java 8 FYI.

Comment: Is there any difference with my router definition? I can't see.

Comment: Correct, there is no. I use the same you provided and I as you see in the test I send the same `payload` and as String. What SI version do you use?

Comment: I use Spring 4.3.7.RELEASE and SI Java DSL 1.1.4.RELEASE

Comment: Spring Integration version, please? How Java DSL is related to the question, please?

Comment: Don't warry: I've already implemented needed functionality in another way. Thank you for help!